# Single image launch screen implementation for cordova hybrid app

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I have gone through splash doc https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen#single-image-launch-screen
Here just using single image of 2732x2732px will show splashes on all devices.

In Android platform section, I have specified below line in config.xml

```
<splash src="www/images/test.png" />
```

I have also added preference for splashscreen

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
```

But this is not working. App is getting crashed when I try to open the app . When I add all splashes with their densities it works as referred in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36045485/4677062. 
Whereas documentation tells that this can be done using single image by just adding one splash to config and not for all the density images as specified in the above link.

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions for single image launch are for iOS not Android.

For Android you should use e.g.:

```
    <splash qualifier="land-hdpi" src="res/android/splash/landscape-hdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-ldpi" src="res/android/splash/landscape-ldpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-mdpi" src="res/android/splash/landscape-mdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="res/android/splash/landscape-xhdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/android/splash/portrait-hdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/android/splash/portrait-ldpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/android/splash/portrait-mdpi.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/android/splash/portrait-xhdpi.png" />
```

Note: res/android/splash/ is my specific path, my custom build system copy files from this folder to www/images/

Comment: Isn't it `density` instead of `qualifier`?